# Issue with package installation - Not in package.xml

Tags: managed-package, package-install

I am installing my managed package into a testing org and getting this error:

[image]

All these labels are included in the package:

[image]

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, as you may be aware managed package beta versions are not upgradable incase you're trying to install new beta version on an org having older version.

Comment: @Raul, I install the package into a fresh new developer org.

Comment: Are you trying to include items from *another* managed package into *your* managed package? I  am not sure you're allowed to do that.

Comment: No, all the items are from my managed package. fflib and ffhttp are just prefixes from financial force's libraries I am using in my project

Comment: In the packaging UI in your packaging org, do you have a button "Refresh Components"?

Comment: No, I don't see the button. Where is it located exactly?

Comment: In the packaging org, in Classic, if you click the package name in the upper right corner of the window ("Developing $MYPACKAGE"), you get to the packaging UI. There's a row of buttons "Add", "View Components", etc. You may see one there that says "Refresh Components", or you may not.

Comment: Well, in my case there is no button "Refresh Components" in the packaging UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from support regarding this problem. It appeared that another component `Custom Object Criteria Based Sharing Rule` was the real cause, not custom labels. I just removed it from the package and installed it successfully.

I wish Salesforce had more informative and what is more precise descriptions for error messages.

It's also worth checking out this page [Components Available in Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) and [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/46) if package installation fails due to the `not in package.xml` error.